# Git stash / detached head

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-stash

I have had a dirty state in my project, which I did not want to commit. I did a git stash, to save it for later. Afterwards I continued and did some commits. The project now is in detached HEAD mode.

Now, I do not care about the stashed changes anymore. How can be the current last commit be made to the new master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of an unneeded stash with `git stash drop [stash-id]` (default is the latest stash, see all with `git stash list`).

You can go back to master by `git checkout master`, but note that this may discard changes in your working directory.

Comment: thanks. deleted the stash, created a branch, merged back the changes into master and finally deleted the branch. everything clean again.